# Error cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: api (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

Estimados tengo este error en mi entorno local y ya no se como resolverlo:

```
cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: api (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

Tambien tengo un problema que no me esta reconociendo el .env ..

Saludos

Comment: Estás usando virtual hosts?

Answer (score 0):

En Mac ve a

```
preferencias de red > avanzado > DNS > agrega 127.0.0.1
```

y que sea el primero de la lista.
Quizás sea necesario que reinicies.